# Adding a number to each column of a matrix

Tags: matrix, tensorflow, vectorization

I have a matrix

```
A = [[  1.  2.  3.]
     [  4.  5.  6.]]
```

and a vector

```
b = [ 5.  10.  15.]
```

I want to add each column of A (`A[:,i]`) to `b[i]`, i.e.

```
[[  6.  12.  18.]
 [  9.  15.  21.]]
```

an easy way to do it would be

```
A = tf.constant([[1., 2, 3],[1, 2, 3]])
b = tf.constant([[5, 10, 15.]])
e = tf.ones((2,1))
a + tf.matmul( e, b ) # outer product "repmat"
```

But it seems terribly wasteful to do this and have to construct an entire auxiliary matrix which we will eventually throw out. Is there a more idomatic way of doing this without writing my own op?

Comment: Why not simply `A+b`?

Comment: That works, haha. Thanks user gonna close this question

Comment: So are you deleting your question or do you wait for the explanation why it works?

Comment: I'd be interested in the explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned you can do `A + b`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.InteractiveSession()
A = tf.constant([[1., 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
b = tf.constant([[5, 10, 15.]])
(A + b).eval()
```

returns:

```
array([[  6.,  12.,  18.],
       [  9.,  15.,  21.]], dtype=float32)
```

The reason this works is because of array broadcasting. The [Numpy broadcasting page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) has great info and tensorflow broadcasting works the same way. Basically for each dimension (moving from trailing dimension to leading dimension) tensorflow/numpy attempts checks to see if the dimensions are compatible (either they have the same number of elements or one of them only has 1 element).

In your case `A` is of shape `[2, 3]` and `b` is of shape `[1, 3]`. The second dimensions match, but because `b` has a first dimension with only a single element that element of `b` is "broadcast" along the first dimension of `A` (two elements).